# How to get folder path of Installed application, from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, directory, installation

Hi I have created 2 WPF application in PC. Lets suppose first is "OneApp" and another is "TwoApp". I have created this in Visual Studio 2012. I have installed OneApp from setup.  Now I want to run "OneApp" by "TwoApp" application programmatically. So how can I find the path of "OneApp" application? Or if we can setup "OneApp" installation directory manually then that will also be great.

**Edit:**

I tried System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName as suggested. But I am getting folder path as below

[image]

Can't I install in Program Files like other normal application?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Do you mean this? [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start)?

Comment: No. I need to know, Where OneApp is installed? so that i can start OneApp Application by "TwoApp" Application.

Comment: Your path looks like the path of an installed ClickOnce application, not one installed using the Setup functionality. If it *is* a ClickOnce application, then that *is* the correct installation path... they're *all* stored in the `AppData` folder for security reasons.

Comment: How can I create build using Setup functionality then?

Comment: See [this video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2aFNtcZfk) for an example of adding a Setup Project to your application... you might be able to find a better one if you look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all hit and try method. I just found a better solution for this problem in a blog. Link is

http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/

My code is to get the application: First get the short cut of that application, then open that shortcut will work fine. You can also see, how to send data to other application in above link.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs));
sb.Append("\\");
//publisher name is OneApp
sb.Append("OneApp");
sb.Append("\\");
//product name is OneApp
sb.Append("OneApp.appref-ms");
string shortcutPath = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(shortcutPath);

//Start the One App installed application from shortcut
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(shortcutPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generally ask the `Assembly` where it is on the hard drive. This should give you a path that starts with `C:\` (if it is on the C drive obviously)... try this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Uri uri = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.CodeBase));
```

In my development environment (Visual Studio), that gives me this:

> C:/DevelopmentProjects/AppName/ProjectName/bin/Debug

eg. it is where the assembly is running from. On an installed application, it should tell you where that assembly is running from.

Comment: But how "TwoApp" can get "OneApp" installation directory? i think "OneApp" installed folder location will be change every time, in every machine?

Comment: @VarunJi : I think you might have to use **registry** to get the path of installed application. You may find it from here - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. Try it out and let us know...

Comment: Yes, if it is a ClickOnce application, that's right. Worse still, it will be in a folder like the one you showed with a horrible guid like name... one that you could never guess or calculate.

Comment: I am new in C#. So please help me out. How to use HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion programatically?

Comment: @VarunJi : But first check in **registry** editor that your **OneApp** key is there in - "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" or not ?? First confirm it.

Comment: I don't think that ClickOnce apps will have a registry key in there... mine don't anyway.

Comment: I think its not there. Yes Sheridan. I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

in  `wifomrs` it is:

```
 Application.StartupPath
```

However that isnt the case for `wpf` , you are looking sth like:

Add System.IO reference:

```
using System.IO;

string baseDir=  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

or

```
string baseDir= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

Comment: I tried System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), but its showing path for current application. Can't we get a static path everytime like other normal application like c:\program files\....